# .htaccess redirect http to https and redirect main page visitor to another page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I know this has been asked several times, but I have checked a lot of the other answers and still couldn't solve my problem.

Let's assume my website is `example.com`

I want to redirect all http address to https, and also redirect all `example.com` visitors to `example.com/main`

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/main/$1 [R,L]
```

It sort of works, but there are some issues.
If I type `www.example.com/main` or `example.com/main` it goes to the http site, instead of the https. Why is that?

Also, if I type `example.com/works/01` it becomes `https://www.example.com/main/works/01`. It adds an extra 'main' folder in.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the request is comming from `http` URL scheme and then redirect that request to a secure connection

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/main/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried your method, but it doesn't work. The same problem still persist.